# how to show array data on UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, uitableview

How to array data reload in UITableView? I use a web services  and fetch data stored in  a array. I got a data and print on consol but same array can't reload  in TableView.

Please help me how to show data on table view i trying to many times but can't show data.

## JSON

```
{
 "status": {
"event": [
  {
    "event_id": "28",
    "event_name": "Event name",
    "event_title": "svsav",
    "img": "http:\/\/edutimeapp.com\/toshow\/chamber-of-commerc\/uploads\/1461402793-Vtcg8pRB.jpg",
    "event_date": "2016-04-05",
    "event_time": "12:00",
    "event_detail": "svsa"
  },
```

## viewcontroller

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "celltable.h"

 @interface ViewController ()
 {

NSArray*name;

}

@end


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
 [self.tableview setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];

NSURLRequest *req=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://edutimeapp.com/toshow/chamber-of-commerc/ws/fetch_event.php"]];
response =[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
 }


 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
  {
  [response appendData:data];
  NSLog(@"error receving data %@",response);
  }

 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 {

  }
 -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
 {
  NSError *error;

  NSLog(@"Error in receiving data %@",error);
  NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&error];
NSLog(@"response data %@",son);

 NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
NSDictionary *retrievedJTransD = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
  NSArray* retrievedJTrans = retrievedJTransD[@"status"][@"event"];
   name = [retrievedJTrans valueForKey:@"event_name"];
NSLog(@"success %@", name);
  }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
return 1;
 }
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [name count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  NSLog(@"tableview cell");
  celltable *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ht"];
if (cell==nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

cell.date.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return  cell;

 }
```

Comment: First thing, try to reload table on main thread. Second,  Make sure numbers of rows function returns > 0.

Comment: Reload Tableview in main thread

Comment: thank you , i reload  in main thread then successfully data reload in table view.

Comment: you are mistake in this line code, `name = [retrievedJTrans valueForKey:@"event_name"];`  I have update your code, please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is cannot reload the tableview, next you did not correctly set the array values, Use this below code,

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
 {
     NSError *error;

     NSLog(@"Error in receiving data %@",error);
     NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&error];
     NSLog(@"response data %@",son);

     NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
     NSDictionary *retrievedJTransD = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
     NSArray* retrievedJTrans = retrievedJTransD[@"status"][@"event"];

     //you are wrong in name array change it.

     name = retrievedJTrans;
     NSLog(@"success %@", name); 

     [self.tableview reloadData];
  }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
     return 1;
 }
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [name count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     NSLog(@"tableview cell");
     celltable *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ht"];
     if (cell==nil)
     {
         NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
     }

    cell.date.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"event_name"]];

   return  cell;

 }
```

hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

After You get response from WS

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   [self.yourTableview reloadData];     
                        });
```

> Always remember that when you need reload tableview and you are using WS Call or any other block operations reload it in main thread